# Angular 5 routes don't work after deployment

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

In my Angular 5 application I've been running locally via `ng serve` and everything is working perfect.  So then I did `ng build -prod` and uploaded the dist folder to my webserver.

The main page opens up and displays properly, but any of the routes that I try to go to result in a 404 error.  I have no idea how to debug/fix this.

Comment: Are you using `href`s or `[routerLink]`s to navigate to your routes?

Comment: The one I'm looking at is an href.

Comment: But even just directly typing the URL into the browser doesn't work.

Comment: OK, changing the href to a routerLink fixed that part.   But I need to be able to directly type the URL into the address bar as well.

Comment: You've to configure your server. So that you're sever can serve `index.html` on every 404 request. Because your server has no idea about client-side routing. Once your server serves `index.html` on 404, angular will take care of the routing.

Comment: Yea, what the CLI is doing is redirecting everything to the index.html. What/where are you hosting your app on?

Comment: I'm using IIS 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first thing first, as discussed above you'll want to be sure to use the `[routerLink]` directive for your routing inside of the app. Using `href`s basically is telling your browser to navigate to a new route, and as a result will make a request to the server for the page and render out that new content (which is the reason why you're getting the `404`, that route doesn't exist on the server, it's just being interpreted by your Angular application).

The `[routerLink]` directive effectively updates the route inside of the application while updating the navigation history of the browser without actually fetching a new page. Older applications actually use a `hashbang` strategy while we're discussing a `push state` strategy... ([Both discussed here if you're interested in learning more](http://singlepageapplication.com/react-app-url-schemes-part-1/))

Either way, like @Ritwick mentioned. At this point you'll want to redirect all server requests to your `index.html` that way if a user navigates to a route from outside of the application you can handle that. Just as some sample snippets you can do this redirection of routes if you're using `NGINX`:

```
index index.html;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Or if you're using something like Firebase you can update your `firebase.json` like so...

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist", // if your app is in a subfolder of the dist, include that
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I told IIS to redirect status 404 to /.  I no longer get a 404 of course but now I'm getting an error in the console saying `ERROR TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`.  Works fine if I don't build with the `-prod` flag

Comment: This might be more of an issue with your application now. I'm not sure if you can share your code. But without knowing more there isn't more help I can provide 

Comment: I think it is, but I have no idea where to look since it appears with any page I go to now and it doesn't happen in the local instance.

Comment: Possibly related => https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9495

And if worse comes to worse (and it may be a pain), I'd look through all `const` variables, or maybe use a linter to see where a `const` is reassigned/unassigned or something.

Comment: Thank you!  That was *exactly* the issue.  I updated to 1.7.3 and now it doesn't give that error.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to use routerLink instead of href.

Example

```
 <a routerLink="/home" class="item-button">Link 1</a> <br/>
```

Comment: This works fine while you're inside the Angular app... but if you then deploy the code and try to use it (eg "http://mikesapp.com/home") it throws a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using Firebase hosting. I found that when deploying the application to Firebase you need to answer Yes to the "Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?" question, which solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your app root, create a file "Staticfile" with the following content:

pushstate: enabled

Push this in your deployment and you should be able to access your links directly from the address bar.

For example: if your source directory is "src" then your file should be located in this folder: i.e. "src/Staticfile". Please note, "Staticfile" is not a directory, it's the file name.

Comment: please provide more details. in the root of angular app or the server? link to some docs?

Comment: @YosiLeibman, I edited my response. I hope that it makes more sense now. Thanks for your remarks.